# Generics in Spring Controller/Service/Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics

I would like to trim down my code to use only one function for filtering.
Filtering should work with 3 different classes: com.example.model.Category, com.example.model.Tag, java.util.Calendar.

Here's my Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/blog" )
public class BlogController
{
    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    private static final int PER_PAGE = 5;

    private static final int ARCHIVE_MONTHS = 12;

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addGlobalObjects( Map<String, Object> map )
    {
        map.put( "section", "blog" );

        SortedMap<Category, Integer> categories = new TreeMap<Category, Integer>();
        for ( Category category : categoryService.list() )
        {
            categories.put( category, articleService.size( category, Category.class ) );
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );

        cal.add( Calendar.MONTH, ARCHIVE_MONTHS * -1 );

        SortedMap<Date, Integer> archive = new TreeMap<Date, Integer>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < ARCHIVE_MONTHS; ++i )
        {
            cal.add( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );
            archive.put( cal.getTime(), articleService.size( cal, Calendar.class ) );
        }

        SortedMap<Tag, Integer> tags = new TreeMap<Tag, Integer>();
        for ( Tag tag : tagService.list() )
        {
            tags.put( tag, articleService.size( tag, Tag.class ) );
        }

        map.put( "categories", categories );
        map.put( "archive", archive );
        map.put( "tags", tags );

        map.put( "categoriesSize", categoryService.size() );
        map.put( "tagsSize", tagService.size() );

        map.put( "date", new Date() );
    }

    @RequestMapping( "/index.html" )
    public String index( HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> map )
    {
        return list( request, map, null, null );
    }

    @RequestMapping( "/archive/{date}.html" )
    public String archive( @PathVariable( "date" ) @DateTimeFormat( iso = ISO.DATE, style = "yyyy/MM" ) Date date, HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> map )
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime( date );

        return list( request, map, cal, Calendar.class );
    }

    private <T> String list( HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> map, Object filterObject, Class<T> clazz )
    {
        int page = ServletRequestUtils.getIntParameter( request, "page", 1 );
        map.put( "articles", articleService.list( page * PER_PAGE - PER_PAGE, PER_PAGE, filterObject, clazz ) );
        map.put( "numPages", Math.ceil( articleService.size() / PER_PAGE ) );
        map.put( "currentPage", page );
        return "articles";
    }
}
```

In my ArticleDAO now I need to implement the methods list/size:

```
@Repository
public class ArticleDAO extends BaseDAO<Article>
{
    public <T> List<Article> list( int offset, int limit, Object filterObject, Class<T> clazz )
    {
        Criteria c = doFilter( filterObject, clazz );

        if ( limit > 0 )
        {
            c.setFirstResult( offset );
            c.setMaxResults( limit );
        }

        return c.list();
    }

    public <T> Integer size( Object filterObject, Class<T> clazz )
    {
        Number ret = ( Number ) doFilter( filterObject, clazz ).setProjection( Projections.rowCount() ).uniqueResult();
        return ret.intValue();
    }

    private <T> Criteria doFilter( Object filterObject, Class<T> clazz )
    {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria( Article.class );

        if ( filterObject != null && clazz != null )
        {
            T filter = clazz.cast( filterObject );

            if ( filter instanceof Calendar )
            {
                // The method set(int, int) is undefined for the type T
                filter.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
                filter.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
                filter.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
                filter.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
                // The method getTime() is undefined for the type T
                Date d1 = filter.getTime();

                // The method getActualMaximum(int) is undefined for the type T
                filter.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, filter.getActualMaximum( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) );
                filter.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23 );
                filter.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 59 );
                filter.set( Calendar.SECOND, 59 );
                Date d2 = filter.getTime();

                criteria.add( Restrictions.between( "creationDate", d1, d2 ) );
            }

            if ( filter instanceof Category )
            {
                // The method getId() is undefined for the type T
                criteria.createCriteria( "categories" ).add( Restrictions.eq( "id", filter.getId() ) );
            }

            if ( filter instanceof Tag )
            {
                // The method getId() is undefined for the type T
                criteria.createCriteria( "tags" ).add( Restrictions.eq( "id", filter.getId() ) );
            }
        }

        return criteria;
    }
}
```

How ArticleDAO.doFilter should look like? I guess I don't understand the Generics stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think generics is buying you anything here.  This won't even compile b/c T is not known and you are trying to call specific methods (e.g. getId()).

There are a few ways you can do this without generics.  The simplest way would be

```
 if ( filterObject instanceof Calendar ) {
   Calendar filterCal = (Calendar) filterObject;

   filterCal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // ... and so on
```

If you do it this way, you can drop the clazz parameter from your methods.  You don't need that clazz.cast() call.

Just a word on generics, I typically find myself using generics when I am doing the same thing regardless of the type.  For instance, it looks like you are using generics successfully for your BaseDAO.  Regardless of the type, BaseDAO saves, updates, deletes, etc.  In your case above, you are trying to do something different based on type.  It doesn't really lend itself to generics.  In fact, doing something different per type usually means you can do it nicely with polymorphism.